# How do I tell pyparsing to discard parts of the parsed string?

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I'm writing a parser for some marked-up data, and I'd like to get pyparsing to discard things like start and end tags in the final result, leaving just the data.

Can I do this, or do I just have to name the value appropriately and pull them out manually?

Comment: If the markup tags look like XML, also check out `makeHTMLTags` and `makeXMLTags` - these helpers do more than just add '<>'s around a string, but also build in support for embedded attributes, upper/lower case variations, and stray whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Suppress" is probably what you want.  You can use the Suppress class explicitly, as in `dont_care = Suppress(Word(alphas))` or call suppress() on any expression, `dont_care = Word(alphas).suppress()`. This will suppress the matched tokens from appearing in the parsed output.